# PHP - strpos - search in all string without offset from X to Y

Tags: php

In strpos function we can define offset - where parser sholud start search our substring in string. I have to create something similar - I have to remove range offsets from string, for exacly:

```
$string = 'This is my string';
echo strpos($string, 'is my', 0);
```

and it will be return something position of substring `is my` in main $string.
But how to tell a PHP script to search in all string (like this script above) but not in position from X to Y? Is it possible?

**Note:**

I'm using `mb_strpos()` but I think, a solution will be very similar for both functions.

Thanks.

Comment: No it is not. Create your custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You need your custom function - that should work for you:

```
//$X<$Y
funciton getOffset($str, $needle, $X, $Y) {
    $str1 = substr($str, 0, $X);
    $str2 = substr($str, $Y);
    $pos1 = strpos($str1, $needle, 0);
    $pos2 = $Y + strpos($str1, 'is my', 0);
    return  false == $pos1 ? $pos2 : $pos1;
}
```